# Top links when login or not login

Tags: customer, xml, login, toplinks

With this parameter in the xml I can add a top link

```
                    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                        <label>Registrati</label>
                        <url>customer/account/create/</url>
                        <title>Registrati</title>
                        <prepare>true</prepare>
                        <position>1</position>
                    </action>
```

How do I add the top link only to users logged on or only for users not logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for logged in users:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Registrati</label>
            <url>customer/account/create/</url>
            <title>Registrati</title>
            <prepare>true</prepare>
            <position>1</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

Only for logged out users:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Registrati</label>
            <url>customer/account/create/</url>
            <title>Registrati</title>
            <prepare>true</prepare>
            <position>1</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```